# Boto3 automatic response for initialised EC2 Instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have an automation to do various stuff using boto3.

```
    def createInstances(self):

        if args.executescript != 0:
            user_data = open(args.executescript).read()
        else:
            user_data = ""

        instances = self.ec2_resource.create_instances(
            ImageId=args.imageid,
            MinCount=1,
            MaxCount=args.maxinstances,
            InstanceType=args.imagetype,
            KeyName="aws_key_pair",
            TagSpecifications=[
                {
                    'ResourceType': 'instance',
                    'Tags': [
                        {
                            'Key': 'Name',
                            'Value': 'instance_ami_1'
                        },
                        {
                            'Key': 'depertment',
                            'Value': 'qa'
                        },
                        {
                            'Key': 'work',
                            'Value': 'ccperformance'
                        },
                        {
                            'Key': "AMI",
                            'Value': "reniassance_jdk8_cc"
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ],
            BlockDeviceMappings=[
                {
                    'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1',
                    'Ebs': {
                        'VolumeSize': 100,
                        'VolumeType': 'standard'
                    }
                }
            ],
            NetworkInterfaces=[
                {
                    'SubnetId': "subnet-0b55a42b7cfc0f3d3",
                    'DeviceIndex': 0,
                    'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
                    # 'Groups': [sg1, sg2]
                }
            ],
            UserData=user_data,

        )
```

I am using `UserData` in create_instances. This will create some log file in the instance. I need to pull then to my local once this is done.

I need a way to tell my script that the instance is now up and running and the script in `UserData` has successfully ran so that I can scp my logs to my local and terminate the instance.

Comment: If you create the instance using cloudformation, you can use cfn-signal to signal user-data has completed running. Otherwise your best bet is probably to poll via SSH on interval until done. If it wasn't going to your local machine you could invoke a lambda from the user data.

Comment: Also, if you're just running a single job and killing the instance, look at [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/)

Comment: Frankly, I'd get the instance to copy its log file to Amazon S3, which you can then easily access/download. Just one additional command to run in the User Data script.

Comment: I thought of using S3 to store the data, but was not sure as I have to pull that anyhow to my local machine. In addition I may still need a mechanism to know if the logs have been copied to S3, so that I can terminate the machines. @John Rotenstein

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for your response. CloudFormation could be useful. can we use monitoring feature somehow to know the status of the machine?

Comment: Just use the AWS CLI `aws s3 sync` command (maybe via a cron job) to replicate the bucket to your local machine. Or, use boto3 to list the bucket and then pay attention to files with a create time since the last batch run.

Comment: Thats really helpful, thanks @JohnRotenstein